# Combining 2 pattern prerequisites in one rule?

Tags: makefile

I am writing a makefile for a project containing c++ files having both .cc and .cpp extensions. There is no difference for the compilation rule which file type to process. I want to eliminate the rule duplication and combine this rule in one line like this: 
    $(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: %.cpp  %.cc
        ...
But it doesn't work. Is it possible at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible.

The best you can do is put the recipe into a variable and use the same variable in both rules:

```
COMPILE.cpp = $(CC) ...

%.o : %.cpp
        $(COMPILE.cpp)
%.o : %.cc
        $(COMPILE.cpp)
```